# Manipulating Opacity in Blackberry 5

Tags: blackberry

I am building a news ticker that needs to be implemented on Blackberry 5.  When transitioning from one element to the next, I am looking at a fade out/fade in transition.  Mostly because I am having trouble finding resources on creating animations in the Blackberry 5 reference.

the basic flow I am looking at is:

```
public void updateUI() {
 //fade out
 //set values
 //fade in
}
```

So far I have all the UI elements contained inside a HorizontalFieldManager.  I have tried digging through the Field and Graphics documents, but did not find what I was looking for.

Keep in mind, supporting Blackberry 5 is the client's requirement, not mine.

Comment: hi what do you want exactly?please provide some more information here. otherwise open this link we will available http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-and-java

Comment: What about implementing some timer on onFocus/ onUnfocus event of the UI elements you are using for ticker... those timer will start animation upon any focus event occurrence. Didn't try it, but you can try this if you think you can achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle animations explicitly, using a timer for transitions.

My typical solution is something like this (inside the paint() method):

```
final long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
final int alpha;
if (startFadeIn != 0) {
    alpha = (int) Math.min((time - startFadeIn) / SPEED, 255);
       if (alpha < 255) {
           invalidate();
       }
} else if (startFadeOut != 0) {
    alpha = (int) Math.max(255 + (startFadeOut - time) / SPEED, 0);
    if (alpha > 0) {
        invalidate();
    }
} else {
    alpha = 255;
}
graphics.setGlobalAlpha(alpha);
```

It burns some CPU cycles (for a short time), but it works.